# Gem error. can't activate faraday (>= 0.7.3, runtime) for ["youtube_it-2.1.1"], already activated faraday-0.5.7 for ["instagram-0.8"]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, faraday-oauth

I am making a Rails(3.0.4) application using the youtube_it API.

I installed the gem using `gem install youtube_it`, but when I run the script I get this error:

```
can't activate faraday (>= 0.7.3, runtime) for ["youtube_it-2.1.1"], already activated faraday-0.5.7 for ["instagram-0.8"]
```

How should I resolve this without removing the existing version of faraday?

Comment: Bundle exec cant be done in my app so I am trying another way to do this, i have put the youtube_it folder in /vendor/plugins/ dir of my application. But i am getting an error "NoMethodError: undefined method `dependency' for Faraday::Request::OAuth:Class" when i do require 'youtube_it'. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be adding **youtube_it** to your Gemfile, then running **bundle install**.

This gives bundler enough information to figure out the dependency graph of all the gems your application needs.  Bundler writes out the needed gems, their dependencies and versions to the **Gemfile.lock** file.

Second, when running the rails command, you shouldn't need to run **bundle exec** according to Yehuda Katz (http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/).   However, in my experience there have been times when bundle exec has been necessary even for the rails command.

In any case, running "**bundle exec *executable***" will run your *executable* (rails, rake, etc) with the gems listed in the **Gemfile.lock**, avoiding the dreaded "can't activate -- already activated" error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You should update faraday to its latest version. Is there a valid reason not to?